# Торрент трекер на php

Tags: php, torrent, ubuntu

Хочу что бы мой сервер на *Ubuntu server* раздавал файлы на подобии [ex.ua](http://ex.ua).

То есть:

1. Пользователь загрузил файл на сервер
2. Автоматически после этого создается раздача этого файла
3. Пользователи могут скачать *.torrent* файл и скачивать/раздавать файлы

Есть ли статьи в инете по этому поводу? Обыскал всё, но кроме непонятной [статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/96880/) ничего не нашёл.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=create+torrent+trackers&oq=create+torrent+tra&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.10241j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=create+torrent+trackers+php

Comment: Для начала надо бы форум написать, а потом уже поверх него трекер. Если не хотите пользоваться готовыми решениями, то кто Вам мешает сесть и написать все это самому?

Comment: @Lucky, сайт у меня есть, просто нужна какая нибудь инструкция или вики, чтобы я написал, я никогда этим не занимался

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».